# Button in one div makes other div scroll to anchor

Tags: jquery, scroll, external, animated

I'm wondering how to make a button in one div scroll to an anchor in another div. The stucture of the anchor looks like this:

```
<a id="organisational_change"></a>
```

The jQuery that I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var consultancyLinks=["organisational_change","organisational_development","executive_coaching","executive_team_development","corp_social_responsibility"];
$("#sidemenu_consultancy #sidemenu_consultancy_btn").each(function(){
$(this).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
});
    $("#sidemenu_consultancy #sidemenu_consultancy_btn").click(function(){
        $('html, body, #content_text').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+consultancyLinks[$(this).index()])},800);
        });
```

});

Any ideas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/position and http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it without any javascript at all:

```
<a id="organisational_change" href="#id_of_other_element"></a>
```

Otherwise, if you want an animation, do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 800);
});
```

Comment: I think you want .position() instead of .offset()

Comment: Depends which element you're scrolling, if you're scrolling the body then you want the offset relative to the document, not the element's parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<div id="btn">
<button id="btn1"/>
</div>

<div id="ancr">
<a id="organisational_change"></a>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:$("#organisational_change").scrollTop},800);
    });
```

});

Comment: Thanks guys...well I ended up writing this:
    $("#sidemenu_consultancy #sidemenu_consultancy_btn").each(function(){
  $(this).css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
  $(this).html("<a href='#"+consultancyLinks[$(this).index()]+"'>"+consultancyNames[$(this).index()]+"</a>");
 });

The animation code doesn't seem to work:
$("#sidemenu_consultancy #sidemenu_consultancy_btn").click(function(){
   $('html, body, #content_text').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+consultancyLinks[$(this).index()])},800);
   
  });

The screen seems to be 'trying' to do it...it kind of shudders for a minute, but nothing.

Comment: Hi Adam if this helped to resolve your query mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact question and now I have a solution that works on mobile, tablet and desktop. But it does require javascript.  Here it is, using your code.  Adjust accordingly.

```
<div id="btn">
<button id="btn1" onclick="ScrollDiv('organisational_change')/>
</div>

<div id="ancr">
<a id="organisational_change"></a>
</div>


 <script>
   function ScrollDiv(yourelement)
     {
      var myDiv         = document.getElementById('ancr');
      var myDivrect     = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
      var Card          = document.getElementById(yourelement);
      var Cardrect      = Card.getBoundingClientRect();
      var CardHeight    = Cardrect.height;
      var DivTopPadding = 25;
      var DivElementPad = 10;
      var Distance   = (DivTopPadding + ((CardHeight + DivElementPad ) * (CardIndex-1)) ;
      myDiv.scrollTo({
                      top: Distance,
                      left: 0,
                      behavior: 'smooth'
                    });
     }
 </script>
```